# How to put question mark as a value in the query and not a placeholder?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite query to update a column if the value of the other column is like question mark ('?') , when I use `update X set a = 'yes' where b like '%%?%%'`, it considers ? as a placeholder. How can I tell it to consider it as a value?

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite `LIKE` operator only has two special characters:

```
%
_
```

Question mark has no special meaning, so you do not need to worry about escaping it.